# npm commands not work

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

No npm command (all!) is working on my Windows 10.

Example:

npm -v

It does not display any information and cmd crashes. Only unlocks if I hit CTR + C and inform "Y":

[image]

I've tried reinstalling node.js (v6.6.0 x64 and v5.12.0 x86), tried npm versions v3.10.3 and v3.10.7, but all without success.

How can I fix it?

**NEWS:**

My `conf.get('prefix')` in afterUser() function on `nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js` it is returning the wrong directory: `C:\Users\Alisson Linneker\'C:\Program`

I believe that this is the problem!

**Problem solved!**

In `nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js` afterUser() function, add before `if (conf.get('prefix')) {` line:

`conf.set('prefix', path.resolve(__dirname, '../..', ''))`

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall nodejs? which version of nodejs are you using?

Comment: @Fabio `I've tried reinstalling node.js, but without success.` Node v6.6.0

Comment: Does nodejs work at all?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy, firewall, whatsoever?

Comment: @Fabio Exactly. None npm commands works

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra Do not use proxy and firewall. Works fine on my OSX VMware.

Comment: @AlissonLinneker that's wasn't quite what I was asking - node isn't an npm command. Try to run node and then write something like "1+1" just to see if it's working

Comment: @Fabio Yes, work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js` afterUser() function, add before `if (conf.get('prefix')) {` line:

`conf.set('prefix', path.resolve(__dirname, '../..', ''))`

Pull request: https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/13995

Answer (score 1):

For Windows I use Virtual Box with Ubuntu.  If you set that up you will have an easier time.

Comment: I would like to use on my Windows host. But the problem has not been solved.